# Using Terraform user_data with Windows Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data

I am trying to create Windows EC2 instance, and I want to change its hostname immediately after creation. I was trying to do it with user_data, but it looks like never gets executed. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Script:

```
<powershell>
Rename-Computer -NewName "Server044"
Restart-Computer
</powershell>
```

Terraform Code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
.
.

user_data = base64encode(file("${"host.ps1"}"))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the modules I work with, we don't use base64encode() for powershell userdata. I think you try dropping that, or else look into the user_data_base64 argument.

Reference: [Terraform > aws_instance > user_data](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data)

Also, remove the unnecessary string interpolation.

`user_data = file("host.ps1")`

You may also try adding the `-Force` parameter to your Rename-Computer cmdlet so it suppresses the confirmation prompt, and `-Restart` to do it with a single command.

```
<powershell>
Rename-Computer -NewName "Server044" -Force -Restart
</powershell>
```

Comment: In the end, I changed the script file to be .txt, and then just used <powershell> tags inside. That worked for me

Answer (score -1):

In the end, I changed the script file to be .txt, and then just used powershell tags inside. That worked for me